# Frameless window with min/max/close buttons (Windows)

Tags: c++, qt5, gdi+, dwm

On Mac there is a window flag/call: `WindowTitleHidden` + `[nativeWindow setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES]`
which basically makes the title bar to be "embedded" inside the window itself instead of creating a frame that "holds" the window. Like this:

[image]

Notice how the minimize, maximize and close buttons are on the same row as the app's widgets.

Is there something similar for Windows?

Like this:

[image]

Code: https://github.com/alexandernst/TrueFramelessWindow

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you must draw them yourself and then reply to the WM_NCHITTEST mesage that Windows sends to your form to query where the mouse is positioned. That way you can tell Windows that the mouse is located over a, say, maximize button, although Windows itself didn't draw one there.

The painting can be done with the help of VisualStyleRenderer or ControlPaint.

I hope these questions will point you further:

[Winforms: Add a close "x" button in a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018980/winforms-add-a-close-x-button-in-a-usercontrol)

[Winforms - WM_NCHITEST message for click on control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392125/winforms-wm-nchitest-message-for-click-on-control)